# How to get out of stream API in python

Tags: python, twitterapi-python

I'm working on a project using a discord bot and the Twitter stream API and I can't figure out how I can get out of the streaming loop and connect the bot to discord because the stream API request act as an infinite loop always waiting for the pieces of information.

Comment: welcome and please check [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you can post some code here, not too much

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I follow here.

I think you first need to establish the connection and then start listening and collect the data.

Comment: You should downvote and flag rather than answer unclear questions

Comment: The issue is that all questions on SO need to be useful to future readers. When you are guessing and OP then updates their question your answer would be invalid

Comment: Makes sense - thanks for clearing that up!